# getting the Warning: React component classes must extend React.Component. on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using the https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit and am getting these warnings:

```
Warning: WithContext(...): React component classes must extend React.Component.
Warning: WithStyles(...): React component classes must extend React.Component.
```

these files look like:

// withContext.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import emptyFunction from 'fbjs/lib/emptyFunction';

function withContext(ComposedComponent) {
  return class WithContext {

    static propTypes = {
      context: PropTypes.shape({
        onInsertCss: PropTypes.func,
        onSetTitle: PropTypes.func,
        onSetMeta: PropTypes.func,
        onPageNotFound: PropTypes.func
      })
    };

    static childContextTypes = {
      onInsertCss: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      onSetTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      onSetMeta: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      onPageNotFound: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    getChildContext() {
      let context = this.props.context;
      return {
        onInsertCss: context.onInsertCss || emptyFunction,
        onSetTitle: context.onSetTitle || emptyFunction,
        onSetMeta: context.onSetMeta || emptyFunction,
        onPageNotFound: context.onPageNotFound || emptyFunction
      };
    }

    render() {
      let { context, ...other } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
      return <ComposedComponent {...other} />;
    }

  };
}

export default withContext;
```

// withStyles.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import invariant from 'fbjs/lib/invariant';
import { canUseDOM } from 'fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment';

let count = 0;

function withStyles(styles) {

  return (ComposedComponent) => class WithStyles {

static contextTypes = {
  onInsertCss: PropTypes.func
};

constructor() {
  this.refCount = 0;
  ComposedComponent.prototype.renderCss = function (css) {
    let style;
    if (canUseDOM) {
      if (this.styleId && (style = document.getElementById(this.styleId))) {
        if ('textContent' in style) {
          style.textContent = css;
        } else {
          style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        }
      } else {
        this.styleId = `dynamic-css-${count++}`;
        style = document.createElement('style');
        style.setAttribute('id', this.styleId);
        style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

        if ('textContent' in style) {
          style.textContent = css;
        } else {
          style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        }

        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
        this.refCount++;
      }
    } else {
      this.context.onInsertCss(css);
    }
  }.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
  if (canUseDOM) {
    invariant(styles.use, `The style-loader must be configured with reference-counted API.`);
    styles.use();
  } else {
    this.context.onInsertCss(styles.toString());
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  styles.unuse();
  if (this.styleId) {
    this.refCount--;
    if (this.refCount < 1) {
      let style = document.getElementById(this.styleId);
      if (style) {
        style.parentNode.removeChild(style);
      }
    }
  }
}

render() {
  return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
}



};
}

export default withStyles;
```

I am completely new to React and ES6 syntax so I am not sure how to fix this. Any help? I started getting these warnings after I switched from React 0.13 to 0.14beta and could not figure out what is causing it. Thanks

Comment: Please tell me that you're not really assigning a prototype method in the constructor?

Comment: Maybe just `class … extends React.Component`?

Comment: I tried it that way but ended up with another error

Comment: …and which one would that be?

Comment: ERROR in ./src/decorators/withStyles.js
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/hilarl/Desktop/client/src/decorators/withStyles.js: Line 17: 'this' is not allowed before super()
      15 | 
      16 |     constructor() {
    > 17 |       this.refCount = 0;

Comment: That means that your constructor is lacking a `super()` call. Put it in the first line and you should be fine.

Comment: What about the is it that you don not understand? It's clear IMO. If you don't know classes very well, [read something about them first](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch3.md#classes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From React v0.14 on, components implemented as ES6 classes *without* extending `React.Component` are deprecated. They should extend `React.Component` (just like the warning says):

```
class Component extends React.Component {

}
```

From the o[fficial blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning):

> ES6 component classes must now extend React.Component in order to enable stateless function components. The [ES3 module pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#other-languages) will continue to work.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to v0.14beta3 today so a bit confused about somethings.

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern is this;

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    var AppCtrlSty = {
        height: '100%',
        padding: '0 10px 0 0'
    }

    class AppCtrlRender extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
                    React 1.3 Basic with browserify and babel
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {}
```

From https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns.